# Error 53 when opening CSV file on mac

Tags: vba, excel, csv

When I try and open a CSV file, I get:

> Error 53: File not found

I get the error on the 4th line, `Open FilePath For Input As #1`
What am I doing wrong?

It is my first time opening a CSV, please be indulgent with my code.

```
Sub opentextfile()
Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = "/Users/christinekelly/Desktop/authors.csv"
file1 = FreeFile
Open FilePath For Input As #file1
row_number = 0
Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #file1, LineFromFile
LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 0).Value = LineItems(2)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 1).Value = LineItems(1)
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 2).Value = LineItems(0)
Number = row_number + 1
Loop
Close #file1
End Sub
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac015.htm also: https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac008.htm

Comment: @Mat'sMug thank you!! I tried the freefile function but I am totally lost.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I tried the freefile function but it is not clear to me.. Could you please give me your advice on how it works in my code? I tried to replace fnum by #1 but got an error. Sub opentextfile()

Dim FilePath As String

FilePath = "/Users/christinekelly/Desktop/authors.csv"

fnum = FreeFile()

Open FilePath For Input As fnum

Write #fnum,

row_number = 0

Do Until EOF(1)

Comment: what version are you running btw?

Comment: @QHarr Very thank you, old version, on mac 2011 v. 14.7.2 It is driving me crazy I can not figure it out:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from looking at @Rebekare's answer to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/304103/opening-a-file-for-output-input-in-microsoft-visual-basic-on-mac-os-x) this is what worked for me.

I went to the file in question `test.csv` and opened the immediate window and typed `?ThisWorkbook.Path` and got `HDD:Users:USER:Desktop`.

I then used the suggested concatenatation of this path with `Application.PathSeparator` & filename i.e.

```
FilePath = "HDD:Users:USER:Desktop" & Application.PathSeparator & "test.csv"
```

This is a useful approach as you get the actual file path syntax and then yield the path separator decision to the `Application`.

Following on from @Mat'sMug suggestion, I found [this](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/99849-vba-path-to-external-hd-on-mac-and-win), which opens the file dialog, and you select the file you want the full path of and it is returned via the message box.

```
Sub PathofFile()
    OpenFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    MsgBox OpenFile
End Sub
```

Within that same link was a suggestion for using the `Dir` function to test if the filepath is valid. If valid you get the filename back, if not you get an error which you can use to determine your next action e.g. the following returns "test.csv" if it exists at that filepath.

```
MsgBox Dir("HDD:Users:USER:Desktop:test.csv")
```

If you are doing other operations with the file you might want to add a test to to see if the file is open first, using Microsoft's [IsFileOpen](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/291295/macro-code-to-check-whether-a-file-is-already-open) function. An example as follows:

```
Sub Test

    If Not IsFileOpen(FilePath) Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    End If

End Sub


Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
    Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

    On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
    filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
    ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
    Close filenum          ' Close the file.
    errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

    ' Check to see which error occurred.
    Select Case errnum

        ' No error occurred.
        ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        Case 0
         IsFileOpen = False

        ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
        ' File is already opened by another user.
        Case 70
            IsFileOpen = True

        ' Another error occurred.
        Case Else
            Error errnum
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: thank you for help! It is very clear with examples provided.

Comment: it was useful for me to think through as do this with Windows all the time but never tried with Mac so was good learning.

Comment: the filepath was "Macintosh HD:Users:christinekelly:Desktop:authors.csv" and not "/Users/christinekelly/Desktop/authors.csv" as indicated when I copy path name from finder