# VBA export worksheet as PDF (Mac 2016) error

Tags: excel, vba, macos, pdf, export

I am struggling to export my worksheet as PDF.

Here is my code, FYI I am using Office 2016 for MAC

```
Sub saveactiveworkbook()

Dim FileName As String
Dim FolderName As String
Dim Folderstring As String
Dim FilePathName As String


ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape



FolderName = "TestVBA"
FileName = "DV" & ".pdf"

  Folderstring = "/Users/Vallier/Documents/Test/TestVBA"
  FilePathName = Folderstring & Application.PathSeparator & FileName

  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
  FilePathName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
  IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

MsgBox FilePathName

End Sub
```

When I launch the program I have a warning box that says: 
"Run-time Error '1004':

Application-Defined or object-defined error"

I try to remedy to this by defining active sheet by "ws" upfront but I then have another error saying:

> "ExportAsFormat of object_ worksheet failed"

Any ideas?

Many Thanks,

Comment: Your problem might be with the start / . Have you tried saving a file in this location and then using GetOpenFileName to see what the actual folder path is that you need?

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693411/error-53-when-opening-csv-file-on-mac/48735319#48735319 and make sure you have a valid path to the file.

Comment: @QHarr unfortunately this doesn't help. I am trying to export a worksheet to pdf, and I derived the path from the terminal

Comment: the terminal path won't necessarily be the same as the path you need for your code to run. This you get as per my link. Are you saying you have no other way to get the path? Apologies if being dense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from Apple's sandboxing rules.  You can no longer save or open directly from VBA to any folder that you want.  You may only write to a folder that Excel has rights to.  This probably includes exporting a PDF, although I have not tested.

Here is an excellent page by Ron de Bruin detailing how to deal with Apple's sandboxing issues in VBA.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac034.htm