# Translating VBA from Windows to Mac to publish to desktop folder

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I used the following Macro in Excel on Windows to 1) take each tab from an Excel workbook, 2) convert to PDF and 3) put in the folder named "Bonus Schedules" on my desktop. I just started a new job where I now have a Mac, and when I try to run the macro I get the error "Error while printing." Can anyone help me convert the script so it works on a Mac? It was suggested to me that the Environ("userinfo") part might be the problem, but the person who thought so didn't know how to change it for a Mac. Thanks!

Sub GeneratePDFs()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim Fname As String

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    On Error Resume Next



Fname = Environ("userinfo") + "\Desktop\Bonus Schedules\" & ws.Name & " - Payout Schedule" & ".pdf"

ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=Fname, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False



Next ws
```

End Sub

Comment: `Environ("userinfo")` is not a standard environment variable. Did you mean it to be `Environ("userprofile")`?

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49502745/1188513) helps.