# Run-time error '75': Path/File access error. Excel VBA 16 Mac OS Ventura 13

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have an Excel VBA code that used to work fine.
After a recent Excel update, the code generates Run-time error '75':Path/File access error.

The code is supposed to open a file for output in the same location where the XLSX file is run from, in this case my DropBox.

```
Sub OpenKMLFile()
    Dim OutputPath As String
        
    OutputPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    
    If InStr(1, OutputPath, "\") >= 1 Then
        'Output File Path for Windows
        OutputPath = OutputPath & "\" & KMLFileName & ".kml"
    ElseIf InStr(1, OutputPath, "/") >= 1 Then
        'Ouotput Path for Mac with '/'
        OutputPath = OutputPath & "/" & KMLFileName & ".kml"
    Else
        'Ouotput Path for Mac with ':'
        OutputPath = OutputPath & ":" & KMLFileName & ".kml"
    End If
    
    KMLFileNumber = FreeFile()
    Open OutputPath For Output As KMLFileNumber
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI `Application.PathSeparator` might be more convenient here: see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013255/why-do-we-need-application-pathseparator

Comment: Does the file already exist?  If Yes is it maybe read-only?

Comment: No, it creates a new file to write the KML data into.

Comment: And you can manually create a file in that location?

Comment: Yes, that's where I also store the Excel XLSX file that I'm running.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.
Because it's a cloud based location mirroring the DropBox cloud drive, it seems it can't access this unless a file already exists there, otherwise I'm guessing that location "doesn't exist" even though there are a bunch of other files in the same folder including the XLSX file that's running this script.

So I created an empty text file in that location:

`/Users/guyfisher/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/GPS/Earth Text/CGS2.kml`

Then ran the VBA script, and it worked, Mac OS requested permission to access the file and then the script was able to write the KML data into that file.